# Can concrete classes have additional methods and fields?

Tags: java, interface

I'm working on an assignment that requires me to create an interface, abstract class then extend 2 concrete classes.

The interface are for bicycles; there are 2 types of bicycles in this system, road bikes and electric bikes. Can my concrete 'electric bicycle' class have additional fields 'isFullCharged' and a method to access this boolean? I can't put this in my abstract or interface because it is not applicable to road bikes..

This module is focused on good java practices and maintaining immutability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, concrete classes can have additional methods and fields. Your electric bicycle class can have the extra members you describe.